# Comparing date object generated from a function and

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I'm trying to compare two dates:

```
var date = new Date('Mon May 11 2000 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)');

var processedDate = new Date(new Date(date.setHours(23,59,59,999)).setDate(date.getDate() -1));
```

and

```
var otherDate = new Date('Wed May 10 2000 23:59:59:999 GMT+0200 (CEST)');
```

console.logging the dates gives exactly the same output, however, the following statement doesn't resolve to true:

```
if (otherDate === processedDate) {
    console.log('equal dates');
}
```

See the following fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/mgvx613d/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: objects cannot be directly compared by equality. Longer answer from [2ality](http://www.2ality.com/2011/03/javascript-values-not-everything-is.html):

> Objects have unique identities and are compared by reference: Every object you create via an expression such as a constructor or a literal is considered different from every other object; a fact that can be observed via the equality operator (===). That operator compares objects by reference: two objects are only equal if they have the same identity. It does not matter whether they have the same content or not.

```
> {} === {}
false

> var obj = {};
> obj === obj
true
```

However you can use the `Date` method [`getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) to compare the millisecond values of the two dates:

```
if (otherDate.getTime() === processedDate.getTime()) {
  console.log('equal dates');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can't compare Object.Try this instead:

```
if (otherDate.toString() === processedDate.toString()) {
    console.log('equal dates');
}
```